# Why is it necessary to run 'npm install' when I already have all the dependence in node_module folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

Why is it necessary to run 'npm install' when I already have all the dependence in node_module folder.

After running 'npm install' successfully on my machine, I  want to setup same project on another machine, why do I require run 'npm install' again when I already have downloaded all the dependence in node_module folder?

Comment: What, exactly, does "give my code to some other machine" entail? And what happens if you don't run the command?

Comment: I want to setup same project on another machine. I copy the complete project folder on another machine.. I have edit the question also.

Comment: No, In my case every time, we require to run this command. sorry for typings mistake, nodemodeule  is same as node_module. I have edit the question also.

Comment: Look at the version in the both system of node . See that the version you have in local should also be there in case of conflict . And share the error when you run the app .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to inform you 2 things:

- As your project depend on some packages (node_modules), same as some packages are dependent on other packages.
- when we install some package with command `npm install package -g` then -g will install it in global folder which can be accessed by any project. by using -g, package is not added to node_modules.

Now here is answer of your problem. There might be possible that some dependencies of packages are installed as global on one machine and not on other one. This can happen as developers work on many project on same machine and might be they have installed global packages. So in this case you need to execute `npm install` command.

Comment: So what is solution of this problem?

Comment: it is good practice to share just `package.json` file. `node_modules` folder should not be shared. Next person or machine will install packages according it need using `package.json`

Comment: also you can use command `npm update`. this will update packages' dependencies and version etc

Comment: I do want that new person should run nothing and will be able to access complete application directly. What is the process for that?

Comment: You can deploy your app on some server. i.e [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [Openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com) etc. Then you can simply share app url

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` extract all your dependencies from your package.json, download it and save them in your node_modules folder. You don't need to run npm install again and again if you already have installed all your dependencies locally.

When ever you installs a new dependency you run `npm install <package-name> --save` and why `--save` for the first time? because it adds the new installed dependency on your package.json. We never push node_modules to our git repo only the updated package.json is pushed to repo. In that case if a new person pulls your code from the repo he is only going to run `npm install` and all the dependencies mentioned on your package.json will going to available on his project locally. Thats a small intro about why we use package.json hope it helps.

Comment: the question is about if he push node_module than he is facing problem.

Comment: Himanshu is right, We have all of the dependecies in node_module, Now new person still required to run command. Why?

Comment: You don't need to run npm install again if all the dependencies mentioned in your package.json are available locally on your machine. Also when you run `npm install` it tells you what packages have been added and if all the packages are already available it will say `up to date in xxs`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of node in both system .

I guess that would be issue. you local system would have either higher version than the server.
 May be not able to compile for higher version make sure the version are same for node in both , to reduce the comflict.

Comment: Do I need to check any thing apart from node package?

Comment: Yes check the node version.